# Google sheets scripting - possible for mail to trigger one column?

Tags: function, google-sheets, triggers, scripting

I am wanting to see if a Google Sheet can trigger my script when a form gets filled onto the sheet - by triggering **Column A** as I need to be emailed when a new request comes through, this can be best done using Column A because that's the cell for full names so I will never edit Column A cells.

Here is my code that is not working so far -

```
function onEdit(e){

  var range = e.range;
  if (range.getColumn() === observedCellColumn && range.getRow() === observedCellRow) {
      myFunction(); // MailApp.sendEmail('email@email.com','Maintenance Request','Hi Connor A resident or staff member has put in a maintenance request. 
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions):

> Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. For
>   example, calling Range.setValue() to edit a cell does not cause the
>   spreadsheet's onEdit trigger to run.

An option would be to use an [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead. To do so:

1. Edit your function:

```
function sendEmail(){
   MailApp.sendEmail('email@email.com','Maintenance Request','Hi Connor A 
   resident or staff member has put in a maintenance request.');
}
```

2. Go to `Edit > Current project's triggers`
3. Click on the `+ Add Trigger` button
4. Select your function and set the Event type as `On form submit`, and save.

Now, each time someone submits the Form you will receive an email. Keep in mind that the users sending it will send it [as your account](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions):

> Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who
>   created them. [...] This means that if you
>   create a trigger to send an email when a document is opened, **the email
>   is always be sent from your account**, not necessarily the account that
>   opened the document. However, you could create an installable trigger
>   for each account, which would result in one email sent from each
>   account.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. Unfortunately your code does not work for my conditions. Someone else has created the auto fill from forms, pretty sure from Jotform. So when a row is filled from a form and my installable trigger is set up, nothing happens. 

To avoid the need to parse the auto fill form with my function, I instead am trying to get Column A to trigger my code because I know I will never edit anything in that Column.